# Google Map Javascript: How to show infowindow only on boundry of geojson city layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Currently, InfoWindow display on entire layer, but i need InfoWindow display only when I hover on boundry of city layer as displayed in image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhawA.png)

```
var cityLayer = new google.maps.Data();
cityLayer.loadGeoJson('laughlin.json');
cityLayer.setStyle({  fillColor: "#f6b234",  fillOpacity:0.4,  strokeColor: "#f6b234",  strokeOpacity:0.8,  strokeWeight: 4,});
cityLayer.setMap(regionMap);
google.maps.event.addListener(cityLayer, 'mouseover', function(eve) {
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>Laughlin</strong></div>');
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(eve.latLng, cityLayer, 10e-4)) {    infowindow.setPosition(eve.latLng);
infowindow.open(regionMap, this); }
});
```

//laughlin.json file content
{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "STATEFP": "32", "PLACEFP": "41000", "PLACENS": "02408587", "GEOID": "3241000", "NAME": "Laughlin","NAMELSAD": "Laughlin CDP", "LSAD": "57", "CLASSFP": "U1", "PCICBSA": "N", "PCINECTA": "N", "MTFCC": "G4210", "FUNCSTAT": "S", "ALAND": 228081857.000000, "AWATER": 3503460.000000, "INTPTLAT": "+35.1485812", "INTPTLON": "-114.7375884" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -114.853371, 35.192431 ], [ -114.852957, 35.192482 ], [ -114.852547, 35.192491 ], [ -114.852039, 35.192457 ], [ -114.851455, 35.192353 ], [ -114.848023, 35.191709 ], [ -114.84182, 35.19068 ], [ -114.838766, 35.190057 ], [ -114.831753, 35.188686 ], [ -114.82954, 35.188218 ], [ -114.826735, 35.187345 ], [ -114.814049, 35.183106 ], [ -114.808265, 35.180993 ], [ -114.803165, 35.179287 ], [ -114.801703, 35.178798 ], [ -114.798065, 35.177581 ], [ -114.792928, 35.175863 ], [ -114.792523, 35.175727 ], [ -114.792428, 35.175695 ], [ -114.792332, 35.175663 ], [ -114.791201, 35.175282 ], [ -114.790123, 35.174919 ], [ -114.79007, 35.174902 ], [ -114.787568, 35.174061 ], [ -114.785065, 35.17322 ], [ -114.782923, 35.1725 ], [ -114.782794, 35.172457 ], [ -114.780523, 35.171694 ], [ -114.779846, 35.171466 ], [ -114.779168, 35.171238 ], [ -114.775275, 35.169929 ], [ -114.773382, 35.169398 ], [ -114.772264, 35.169185 ], [ -114.772009, 35.169137 ], [ -114.77046, 35.168979 ], [ -114.769184, 35.168924 ], [ -114.767925, 35.168955 ], [ -114.766417, 35.169085 ], [ -114.75779, 35.170764 ], [ -114.746734, 35.172915 ], [ -114.743444, 35.173556 ], [ -114.741275, 35.173838 ], [ -114.739615, 35.173986 ], [ -114.738182, 35.174045 ], [ -114.737786, 35.174061 ], [ -114.736117, 35.174047 ], [ -114.733584, 35.173919 ], [ -114.732971, 35.173847 ], [ -114.728839, 35.173362 ], [ -114.728183, 35.173275 ], [ -114.726487, 35.173049 ], [ -114.72483, 35.172761 ], [ -114.723888, 35.172572 ], [ -114.723098, 35.172425 ], [ -114.72157, 35.172226 ], [ -114.72082, 35.17217 ], [ -114.719303, 35.172125 ], [ -114.717437, 35.172181 ], [ -114.712559, 35.172329 ], [ -114.712221, 35.172317 ], [ -114.710517, 35.172258 ], [ -114.709472, 35.172108 ], [ -114.708698, 35.171998 ], [ -114.707201, 35.171706 ], [ -114.706745, 35.17162 ], [ -114.703605, 35.171024 ], [ -114.701332, 35.170585 ], [ -114.700744, 35.170472 ], [ -114.69937, 35.170221 ], [ -114.698614, 35.17011 ], [ -114.697951, 35.170012 ], [ -114.69592, 35.169751 ], [ -114.693103, 35.169428 ], [ -114.693078, 35.169425 ], [ -114.6879, 35.16883 ], [ -114.686645, 35.168787 ], [ -114.68596, 35.16887 ], [ -114.684985, 35.169163 ], [ -114.684171, 35.169545 ], [ -114.683476, 35.170024 ], [ -114.682835, 35.17069 ], [ -114.682486, 35.171166 ], [ -114.682161, 35.171871 ], [ -114.681989, 35.172635 ], [ -114.681977, 35.17323 ], [ -114.682108, 35.174234 ], [ -114.682481, 35.176332 ], [ -114.682894, 35.178648 ], [ -114.682894, 35.17892 ], [ -114.682848, 35.179199 ], [ -114.682643, 35.180772 ], [ -114.68256, 35.181241 ], [ -114.682453, 35.18184 ], [ -114.68244, 35.181907 ], [ -114.682416, 35.182049 ], [ -114.682418, 35.182112 ], [ -114.682421, 35.182181 ], [ -114.68245, 35.182964 ], [ -114.682743, 35.183846 ], [ -114.683114, 35.184959 ], [ -114.683305, 35.187102 ], [ -114.683381, 35.187466 ], [ -114.683756, 35.188237 ], [ -114.684088, 35.188723 ], [ -114.684138, 35.188796 ], [ -114.684556, 35.189438 ], [ -114.684739, 35.190079 ], [ -114.684724, 35.190272 ], [ -114.684673, 35.190928 ], [ -114.684598, 35.191242 ], [ -114.684458, 35.19153 ], [ -114.683356, 35.193047 ], [ -114.683171, 35.193502 ], [ -114.683038, 35.193992 ], [ -114.682991, 35.194493 ], [ -114.683022, 35.194879 ], [ -114.68305, 35.195218 ], [ -114.683589, 35.197457 ], [ -114.683637, 35.197733 ], [ -114.683701, 35.198172 ], [ -114.683661, 35.19859 ], [ -114.683572, 35.199 ], [ -114.683443, 35.199389 ], [ -114.683266, 35.199748 ], [ -114.683053, 35.200064 ], [ -114.682794, 35.200363 ], [ -114.682484, 35.200649 ], [ -114.682272, 35.200814 ], [ -114.682061, 35.200958 ], [ -114.681725, 35.201155 ], [ -114.681489, 35.20127 ], [ -114.681238, 35.201376 ], [ -114.680969, 35.201473 ], [ -114.680692, 35.201553 ], [ -114.680421, 35.201614 ], [ -114.680153, 35.201657 ], [ -114.679883, 35.201684 ], [ -114.679562, 35.201692 ], [ -114.679087, 35.201664 ], [ -114.678445, 35.201576 ], [ -114.677792, 35.201469 ], [ -114.677528, 35.201436 ], [ -114.677093, 35.201397 ], [ -114.676656, 35.201379 ], [ -114.676212, 35.201391 ], [ -114.675805, 35.201427 ], [ -114.674885, 35.201584 ], [ -114.674159, 35.201665 ], [ -114.673782, 35.201684 ], [ -114.673611, 35.201693 ], [ -114.673271, 35.201691 ], [ -114.672932, 35.201673 ], [ -114.672751, 35.201653 ], [ -114.672392, 35.201595 ], [ -114.672032, 35.201517 ], [ -114.671138, 35.201253 ], [ -114.668859, 35.200607 ], [ -114.668238, 35.200431 ], [ -114.666357, 35.199923 ], [ -114.665428, 35.199643 ], [ -114.664972, 35.199486 ], [ -114.6642, 35.199194 ], [ -114.663819, 35.199039 ], [ -114.663217, 35.198774 ], [ -114.662629, 35.198491 ], [ -114.66209, 35.198209 ], [ -114.661603, 35.197926 ], [ -114.661306, 35.197754 ], [ -114.660453, 35.197309 ], [ -114.660277, 35.197218 ], [ -114.659824, 35.19696 ], [ -114.659362, 35.196713 ], [ -114.659128, 35.196593 ], [ -114.658653, 35.196364 ], [ -114.657982, 35.196058 ], [ -114.65769, 35.195938 ], [ -114.657431, 35.19585 ], [ -114.657099, 35.195759 ], [ -114.6567, 35.195698 ], [ -114.656373, 35.195668 ], [ -114.656046, 35.19566 ], [ -114.655744, 35.19567 ], [ -114.655594, 35.195682 ], [ -114.65537, 35.19571 ], [ -114.654709, 35.195862 ], [ -114.654409, 35.195915 ], [ -114.654108, 35.195961 ], [ -114.653804, 35.195989 ], [ -114.653651, 35.195994 ], [ -114.653343, 35.195989 ], [ -114.652903, 35.195967 ], [ -114.652509, 35.195934 ], [ -114.65081, 35.19575 ], [ -114.648078, 35.195429 ], [ -114.647023, 35.195317 ], [ -114.646674, 35.19527 ], [ -114.646082, 35.195178 ], [ -114.645789, 35.195122 ], [ -114.645502, 35.195051 ], [ -114.64535, 35.195005 ], [ -114.645049, 35.194899 ], [ -114.644611, 35.194718 ], [ -114.644224, 35.194523 ], [ -114.643854, 35.194305 ], [ -114.643256, 35.19392 ], [ -114.642459, 35.193372 ], [ -114.64156, 35.192725 ], [ -114.640263, 35.191755 ], [ -114.639959, 35.191542 ], [ -114.639691, 35.191354 ], [ -114.639297, 35.191101 ], [ -114.638614, 35.190688 ], [ -114.63826, 35.190499 ], [ -114.638087, 35.190418 ], [ -114.637733, 35.190267 ], [ -114.637225, 35.190063 ], [ -114.636769, 35.189924 ], [ -114.636293, 35.189785 ], [ -114.635525, 35.189582 ], [ -114.635235, 35.189515 ], [ -114.634651, 35.189393 ], [ -114.633476, 35.189168 ], [ -114.63289, 35.189048 ], [ -114.632704, 35.189008 ], [ -114.631142, 35.188669 ], [ -114.626458, 35.187654 ], [ -114.624897, 35.187316 ], [ -114.623797, 35.187087 ], [ -114.621257, 35.186503 ], [ -114.620975, 35.186439 ], [ -114.618714, 35.185927 ], [ -114.616823, 35.185506 ], [ -114.613036, 35.184682 ], [ -114.609203, 35.183845 ], [ -114.608691, 35.183734 ], [ -114.60528, 35.18298 ], [ -114.60479, 35.182872 ], [ -114.604362, 35.182779 ], [ -114.603141, 35.182515 ], [ -114.602686, 35.182418 ], [ -114.601609, 35.182188 ], [ -114.601491, 35.182163 ], [ -114.600697, 35.181967 ], [ -114.600543, 35.182333 ], [ -114.60051, 35.182399 ], [ -114.60037, 35.182613 ], [ -114.600184, 35.18277 ], [ -114.599914, 35.182955 ], [ -114.599813, 35.183016 ], [ -114.599611, 35.183113 ], [ -114.599396, 35.183191 ], [ -114.599262, 35.183228 ], [ -114.599125, 35.183256 ], [ -114.598745, 35.183304 ], [ -114.598462, 35.18336 ], [ -114.597977, 35.183442 ], [ -114.597712, 35.183495 ], [ -114.597579, 35.183525 ], [ -114.59717, 35.18362 ], [ -114.596312, 35.183846 ], [ -114.595492, 35.184094 ], [ -114.593441, 35.184737 ], [ -114.592922, 35.184891 ], [ -114.59108, 35.185455 ], [ -114.590208, 35.18573 ], [ -114.589101, 35.186064 ], [ -114.587728, 35.186492 ], [ -114.586944, 35.186727 ], [ -114.586905, 35.186737 ], [ -114.586552, 35.186836 ], [ -114.586316, 35.186891 ], [ -114.585879, 35.186974 ], [ -114.585679, 35.187005 ], [ -114.584982, 35.187092 ], [ -114.584817, 35.187104 ], [ -114.584406, 35.187124 ], [ -114.584161, 35.187128 ], [ -114.583684, 35.187118 ], [ -114.583246, 35.187087 ], [ -114.583227, 35.187085 ], [ -114.582919, 35.18705 ], [ -114.582555, 35.186997 ], [ -114.582047, 35.18691 ], [ -114.581781, 35.186857 ], [ -114.581679, 35.186832 ], [ -114.580907, 35.186649 ], [ -114.580622, 35.18659 ], [ -114.580299, 35.186547 ], [ -114.580119, 35.186534 ], [ -114.579931, 35.186529 ], [ -114.579742, 35.186533 ], [ -114.579492, 35.186549 ], [ -114.579304, 35.186572 ], [ -114.579116, 35.186606 ], [ -114.578924, 35.186651 ], [ -114.578722, 35.18671 ], [ -114.57852, 35.186781 ], [ -114.578315, 35.186863 ], [ -114.578043, 35.186996 ], [ -114.577907, 35.187075 ], [ -114.57778, 35.187157 ], [ -114.577531, 35.187341 ], [ -114.577409, 35.187444 ], [ -114.577306, 35.187542 ], [ -114.577278, 35.187571 ], [ -114.57721, 35.187645 ], [ -114.577136, 35.187737 ], [ -114.576996, 35.187934 ], [ -114.576931, 35.18804 ], [ -114.576818, 35.188249 ], [ -114.576697, 35.188506 ], [ -114.576665, 35.188597 ], [ -114.576615, 35.188783 ], [ -114.57658, 35.188953 ], [ -114.576558, 35.189061 ], [ -114.576477, 35.189632 ], [ -114.576432, 35.189951 ], [ -114.576298, 35.190779 ], [ -114.576221, 35.191388 ], [ -114.576177, 35.191674 ], [ -114.576073, 35.192354 ], [ -114.576056, 35.192462 ], [ -114.576051, 35.192498 ], [ -114.576024, 35.192675 ], [ -114.576002, 35.192788 ], [ -114.575982, 35.192897 ], [ -114.575975, 35.192986 ], [ -114.575967, 35.1931 ], [ -114.575943, 35.193254 ], [ -114.57593, 35.193343 ], [ -114.575845, 35.193904 ], [ -114.575777, 35.194423 ], [ -114.575586, 35.195587 ], [ -114.575517, 35.196013 ], [ -114.575498, 35.196148 ], [ -114.575358, 35.197159 ], [ -114.575265, 35.197811 ], [ -114.575216, 35.198093 ], [ -114.575189, 35.198318 ], [ -114.575103, 35.198764 ], [ -114.575039, 35.198902 ], [ -114.574931, 35.199051 ], [ -114.574729, 35.199283 ], [ -114.574589, 35.199402 ], [ -114.574355, 35.199555 ], [ -114.574202, 35.199633 ], [ -114.574038, 35.199699 ], [ -114.573866, 35.199748 ], [ -114.573697, 35.199776 ], [ -114.57345, 35.199777 ], [ -114.573283, 35.199767 ], [ -114.572715, 35.199661 ], [ -114.572404, 35.199613 ], [ -114.571802, 35.199507 ], [ -114.571804, 35.199376 ], [ -114.571811, 35.198986 ], [ -114.571814, 35.198857 ], [ -114.571845, 35.19853 ], [ -114.571864, 35.198334 ], [ -114.571824, 35.197937 ], [ -114.571799, 35.197682 ], [ -114.571785, 35.197553 ], [ -114.571753, 35.197229 ], [ -114.571723, 35.196903 ], [ -114.571693, 35.196578 ], [ -114.571679, 35.196441 ], [ -114.571596, 35.19553 ], [ -114.5715, 35.194482 ], [ -114.571463, 35.194083 ], [ -114.571412, 35.193525 ], [ -114.571412, 35.193297 ], [ -114.571394, 35.192122 ], [ -114.571402, 35.191075 ], [ -114.571404, 35.191026 ], [ -114.571014, 35.189913 ], [ -114.57037, 35.18852 ], [ -114.570305, 35.188346 ], [ -114.569653, 35.186267 ], [ -114.569489, 35.185085 ], [ -114.569442, 35.184746 ], [ -114.569384, 35.184329 ], [ -114.569279, 35.183573 ], [ -114.569258, 35.183424 ], [ -114.569245, 35.182539 ], [ -114.569242, 35.18162 ], [ -114.569238, 35.178872 ], [ -114.569242, 35.17796 ], [ -114.569252, 35.177639 ], [ -114.569161, 35.176776 ], [ -114.568989, 35.175085 ], [ -114.569177, 35.173239 ], [ -114.569214, 35.17289 ], [ -114.56876, 35.172195 ], [ -114.568787, 35.171444 ], [ -114.568869, 35.169193 ], [ -114.568879, 35.169128 ], [ -114.568874, 35.16908 ], [ -114.568867, 35.169018 ], [ -114.568886, 35.168443 ], [ -114.568957, 35.167731 ], [ -114.569172, 35.165595 ], [ -114.569244, 35.164884 ], [ -114.5693, 35.16437 ], [ -114.569345, 35.163974 ], [ -114.569446, 35.163063 ], [ -114.569472, 35.16283 ], [ -114.569488, 35.16269 ], [ -114.569529, 35.162317 ], [ -114.569625, 35.161918 ], [ -114.570205, 35.159504 ], [ -114.570301, 35.159105 ], [ -114.570626, 35.157888 ], [ -114.571171, 35.155845 ], [ -114.571209, 35.155707 ], [ -114.571626, 35.154139 ], [ -114.573553, 35.146902 ], [ -114.573879, 35.145351 ], [ -114.573972, 35.14404 ], [ -114.573943, 35.143892 ], [ -114.573706, 35.142698 ], [ -114.573536, 35.142306 ], [ -114.573472, 35.142158 ], [ -114.573299, 35.141699 ], [ -114.572965, 35.140812 ], [ -114.572597, 35.139557 ], [ -114.572953, 35.138485 ], [ -114.572958, 35.138472 ], [ -114.573503, 35.137048 ], [ -114.573703, 35.136583 ], [ -114.574411, 35.13495 ], [ -114.575985, 35.132665 ], [ -114.5771, 35.131048 ], [ -114.577146, 35.130982 ], [ -114.577182, 35.130913 ], [ -114.577324, 35.130638 ], [ -114.577465, 35.130362 ], [ -114.5778, 35.12971 ], [ -114.578263, 35.12881 ], [ -114.579882, 35.127506 ], [ -114.580769, 35.127116 ], [ -114.5815, 35.126796 ], [ -114.581917, 35.126607 ], [ -114.582006, 35.126566 ], [ -114.583063, 35.126086 ], [ -114.584877, 35.125194 ], [ -114.585317, 35.125037 ], [ -114.586186, 35.124729 ], [ -114.588364, 35.123958 ], [ -114.589787, 35.123522 ], [ -114.594105, 35.122558 ], [ -114.597794, 35.121735 ], [ -114.599504, 35.121662 ], [ -114.600694, 35.121611 ], [ -114.601058, 35.121596 ], [ -114.602007, 35.121641 ], [ -114.60274, 35.121666 ], [ -114.602958, 35.121595 ], [ -114.603482, 35.121424 ], [ -114.604007, 35.121252 ], [ -114.605799, 35.121338 ], [ -114.606039, 35.12135 ], [ -114.608071, 35.121447 ], [ -114.611176, 35.121596 ], [ -114.611556, 35.121615 ], [ -114.61297, 35.121622 ], [ -114.613034, 35.121624 ], [ -114.613227, 35.121635 ], [ -114.613293, 35.121639 ], [ -114.613377, 35.121643 ], [ -114.613638, 35.121659 ], [ -114.613725, 35.121666 ], [ -114.614139, 35.121694 ], [ -114.615384, 35.121781 ], [ -114.615799, 35.121811 ], [ -114.616083, 35.121808 ], [ -114.616112, 35.121802 ], [ -114.616424, 35.121742 ], [ -114.616551, 35.121734 ], [ -114.616749, 35.121723 ], [ -114.61702, 35.121708 ], [ -114.617047, 35.121709 ], [ -114.617108, 35.121714 ], [ -114.617254, 35.121725 ], [ -114.617358, 35.121751 ], [ -114.61836, 35.121749 ], [ -114.618697, 35.121749 ], [ -114.619802, 35.121655 ], [ -114.621341, 35.121383 ], [ -114.622329, 35.12121 ], [ -114.624954, 35.120742 ], [ -114.625807, 35.120514 ], [ -114.626316, 35.120423 ], [ -114.628993, 35.119411 ], [ -114.627946, 35.119653 ], [ -114.624808, 35.120366 ], [ -114.623761, 35.120602 ], [ -114.624671, 35.120229 ], [ -114.62513, 35.12004 ], [ -114.625581, 35.119856 ], [ -114.625799, 35.119766 ], [ -114.626329, 35.119637 ], [ -114.626891, 35.119501 ], [ -114.628427, 35.118943 ], [ -114.629304, 35.118552 ], [ -114.629377, 35.11852 ], [ -114.629934, 35.118272 ], [ -114.630441, 35.118009 ], [ -114.630538, 35.117958 ], [ -114.630636, 35.117908 ], [ -114.630708, 35.11787 ], [ -114.630926, 35.117757 ], [ -114.630999, 35.11772 ], [ -114.631949, 35.117251 ], [ -114.632282, 35.117088 ], [ -114.6334, 35.116032 ], [ -114.633678, 35.11577 ], [ -114.634331, 35.115169 ], [ -114.635111, 35.114453 ], [ -114.635182, 35.114385 ], [ -114.635395, 35.11418 ], [ -114.635467, 35.114113 ], [ -114.635945, 35.113718 ], [ -114.636423, 35.113323 ], [ -114.636709, 35.113086 ], [ -114.637432, 35.112489 ], [ -114.639008, 35.110915 ], [ -114.64008, 35.109635 ], [ -114.641116, 35.108401 ], [ -114.641231, 35.108302 ], [ -114.641577, 35.108007 ], [ -114.641693, 35.107909 ], [ -114.643006, 35.106791 ], [ -114.643247, 35.106631 ], [ -114.644354, 35.105903 ], [ -114.645152, 35.104995 ], [ -114.646078, 35.103107 ], [ -114.646758, 35.101877 ], [ -114.646764, 35.101868 ], [ -114.646588, 35.100868 ], [ -114.646579, 35.10082 ], [ -114.646003, 35.100079 ], [ -114.645729, 35.099709 ], [ -114.645642, 35.09959 ], [ -114.644815, 35.098684 ], [ -114.644507, 35.098346 ], [ -114.644351, 35.098173 ], [ -114.643885, 35.097657 ], [ -114.643833, 35.0976 ], [ -114.643729, 35.097487 ], [ -114.643576, 35.09732 ], [ -114.643368, 35.097092 ], [ -114.643119, 35.096819 ], [ -114.643008, 35.096697 ], [ -114.642967, 35.096652 ], [ -114.642831, 35.096503 ], [ -114.642528, 35.096377 ], [ -114.642337, 35.096297 ], [ -114.641649, 35.096011 ], [ -114.640346, 35.095341 ], [ -114.639691, 35.095005 ], [ -114.639677, 35.094975 ], [ -114.639633, 35.094921 ], [ -114.639597, 35.094876 ], [ -114.639457, 35.094771 ], [ -114.639389, 35.094741 ], [ -114.63937, 35.094733 ], [ -114.639291, 35.094713 ], [ -114.639164, 35.09468 ], [ -114.639129, 35.094672 ], [ -114.638962, 35.094645 ], [ -114.638776, 35.09463 ], [ -114.638646, 35.09462 ], [ -114.638034, 35.094409 ], [ -114.636198, 35.093776 ], [ -114.635586, 35.093566 ], [ -114.634913, 35.093374 ], [ -114.632895, 35.092798 ], [ -114.632223, 35.092607 ], [ -114.632189, 35.092597 ], [ -114.632087, 35.092568 ], [ -114.632053, 35.092559 ], [ -114.628171, 35.090831 ], [ -114.627354, 35.090468 ], [ -114.625799, 35.089833 ], [ -114.622517, 35.088703 ], [ -114.618718, 35.086696 ], [ -114.61865, 35.08666 ], [ -114.618582, 35.086624 ], [ -114.61842, 35.086539 ], [ -114.616658, 35.085461 ], [ -114.615507, 35.084757 ], [ -114.613132, 35.083097 ], [ -114.612603, 35.082681 ], [ -114.612556, 35.082644 ], [ -114.612084, 35.082263 ], [ -114.609508, 35.080183 ], [ -114.608987, 35.079707 ], [ -114.607999, 35.078805 ], [ -114.607701, 35.078533 ], [ -114.607168, 35.077912 ], [ -114.607075, 35.077804 ], [ -114.606637, 35.077295 ], [ -114.605545, 35.075961 ], [ -114.605407, 35.075768 ], [ -114.604891, 35.075047 ], [ -114.604736, 35.07483 ], [ -114.604401, 35.074156 ], [ -114.604356, 35.074066 ], [ -114.604311, 35.073976 ], [ -114.604285, 35.073923 ], [ -114.604207, 35.073767 ], [ -114.604182, 35.073715 ], [ -114.603175, 35.070445 ], [ -114.603016, 35.069339 ], [ -114.602908, 35.068588 ], [ -114.602929, 35.068261 ], [ -114.603042, 35.06654 ], [ -114.603098, 35.066316 ], [ -114.603619, 35.064226 ], [ -114.604668, 35.06185 ], [ -114.604715, 35.061744 ], [ -114.604863, 35.061534 ], [ -114.606694, 35.058941 ], [ -114.609138, 35.05659 ], [ -114.609278, 35.056455 ], [ -114.610701, 35.055458 ], [ -114.611692, 35.055001 ], [ -114.611871, 35.054904 ], [ -114.614342, 35.05358 ], [ -114.615902, 35.05272 ], [ -114.616776, 35.052157 ], [ -114.616918, 35.052066 ], [ -114.617111, 35.051944 ], [ -114.617347, 35.051793 ], [ -114.617446, 35.051731 ], [ -114.617491, 35.051703 ], [ -114.617824, 35.051573 ], [ -114.619238, 35.051026 ], [ -114.620652, 35.050479 ], [ -114.621868, 35.051213 ], [ -114.627268, 35.054594 ], [ -114.649651, 35.068088 ], [ -114.651082, 35.066454 ], [ -114.653768, 35.063388 ], [ -114.65729, 35.058854 ], [ -114.66347, 35.050897 ], [ -114.663559, 35.050783 ], [ -114.665139, 35.048782 ], [ -114.669553, 35.043196 ], [ -114.670149, 35.042441 ], [ -114.670686, 35.041762 ], [ -114.671819, 35.040328 ], [ -114.672518, 35.039441 ], [ -114.674615, 35.036783 ], [ -114.675315, 35.035897 ], [ -114.675956, 35.036421 ], [ -114.677882, 35.037993 ], [ -114.678524, 35.038517 ], [ -114.679003, 35.038904 ], [ -114.680443, 35.040068 ], [ -114.680541, 35.040147 ], [ -114.680923, 35.040456 ], [ -114.681441, 35.040874 ], [ -114.682995, 35.04213 ], [ -114.683438, 35.042489 ], [ -114.683513, 35.04255 ], [ -114.683978, 35.042926 ], [ -114.685374, 35.044054 ], [ -114.68584, 35.04443 ], [ -114.690173, 35.047931 ], [ -114.693499, 35.050619 ], [ -114.695759, 35.052491 ], [ -114.702737, 35.058119 ], [ -114.703155, 35.058456 ], [ -114.706796, 35.061393 ], [ -114.707492, 35.061954 ], [ -114.707665, 35.062094 ], [ -114.708186, 35.062514 ], [ -114.70836, 35.062654 ], [ -114.70932, 35.063428 ], [ -114.711354, 35.065068 ], [ -114.712211, 35.065741 ], [ -114.713182, 35.066503 ], [ -114.714117, 35.067237 ], [ -114.715534, 35.068394 ], [ -114.722548, 35.07412 ], [ -114.724887, 35.076029 ], [ -114.725037, 35.076152 ], [ -114.725489, 35.076521 ], [ -114.72564, 35.076644 ], [ -114.726275, 35.077162 ], [ -114.72818, 35.078717 ], [ -114.728816, 35.079236 ], [ -114.729802, 35.08004 ], [ -114.729901, 35.080116 ], [ -114.731561, 35.081386 ], [ -114.733186, 35.082719 ], [ -114.734267, 35.083606 ], [ -114.734614, 35.08389 ], [ -114.735655, 35.084745 ], [ -114.736003, 35.08503 ], [ -114.736445, 35.085392 ], [ -114.737773, 35.086481 ], [ -114.738216, 35.086844 ], [ -114.738825, 35.087343 ], [ -114.739546, 35.087934 ], [ -114.743536, 35.091206 ], [ -114.744733, 35.092187 ], [ -114.744867, 35.092297 ], [ -114.74519, 35.092562 ], [ -114.74616, 35.093357 ], [ -114.746484, 35.093622 ], [ -114.746618, 35.093732 ], [ -114.747022, 35.094063 ], [ -114.747157, 35.094174 ], [ -114.749318, 35.095945 ], [ -114.749572, 35.096154 ], [ -114.756809, 35.102106 ], [ -114.759222, 35.104091 ], [ -114.761801, 35.106212 ], [ -114.765601, 35.109337 ], [ -114.769568, 35.112544 ], [ -114.772166, 35.114645 ], [ -114.772397, 35.114832 ], [ -114.773092, 35.115393 ], [ -114.773324, 35.115581 ], [ -114.776247, 35.117944 ], [ -114.779626, 35.120675 ], [ -114.780264, 35.121175 ], [ -114.783733, 35.12389 ], [ -114.784631, 35.124619 ], [ -114.785068, 35.124973 ], [ -114.787878, 35.127253 ], [ -114.787988, 35.127342 ], [ -114.788697, 35.12792 ], [ -114.788982, 35.128151 ], [ -114.791245, 35.129984 ], [ -114.791971, 35.130572 ], [ -114.792967, 35.13138 ], [ -114.797341, 35.134927 ], [ -114.801313, 35.13803 ], [ -114.803864, 35.140082 ], [ -114.804571, 35.14065 ], [ -114.804902, 35.140916 ], [ -114.805128, 35.141098 ], [ -114.805807, 35.141644 ], [ -114.806034, 35.141827 ], [ -114.807185, 35.142753 ], [ -114.807793, 35.143242 ], [ -114.81064, 35.145531 ], [ -114.811591, 35.146296 ], [ -114.811792, 35.146458 ], [ -114.813531, 35.147856 ], [ -114.815122, 35.149135 ], [ -114.81878, 35.152013 ], [ -114.81915, 35.152304 ], [ -114.820525, 35.153405 ], [ -114.823562, 35.155835 ], [ -114.824408, 35.156513 ], [ -114.826118, 35.157882 ], [ -114.827555, 35.159031 ], [ -114.827811, 35.159237 ], [ -114.832673, 35.163128 ], [ -114.835711, 35.165559 ], [ -114.838426, 35.167615 ], [ -114.840297, 35.169031 ], [ -114.846574, 35.173783 ], [ -114.84929, 35.17584 ], [ -114.84933, 35.176002 ], [ -114.849453, 35.176493 ], [ -114.849495, 35.176658 ], [ -114.849966, 35.178662 ], [ -114.850237, 35.17982 ], [ -114.850436, 35.180666 ], [ -114.850555, 35.18117 ], [ -114.851466, 35.1849 ], [ -114.852011, 35.187047 ], [ -114.852086, 35.187346 ], [ -114.8521, 35.1874 ], [ -114.85256, 35.189286 ], [ -114.852683, 35.189789 ], [ -114.852951, 35.190862 ], [ -114.853289, 35.192207 ], [ -114.853364, 35.192396 ], [ -114.853371, 35.192431 ] ] ] } }]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [isLocationOnEdge function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) provided by Google Maps API.

It has the following syntax :

> isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)

You can change the tolerance level as per your requirements.

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/joysonds/dr1m7xvb/

```
function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
         zoom: 12
     });


   // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
      var triangleCoords = [
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
      ];

      // Construct the polygon.
      var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"Test", maxWidth:200, disableAutoPan:true });

     google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function(event) {
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, bermudaTriangle, 10e-4)) {
                infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);infowindow.open(map);
          }
     });
 }
```

Comment: I am using loadGeoJson, in json file geometry type is Polygon.TypeError: g is undefined

Comment: I have edit my question and also write code and json content which I am using